# Design pattern for RootController and multiple ViewController's

Tags: iphone, xcode, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to have a single class managing multiple views, just like bellow:

```
AppDelegate
  RootController
    ViewController1 + View1.xib
    ViewController2 + View2.xib
```

The logic of my application would be in RootController.

What is the best design pattern for this purpose ? Should my RootController extend `UINavigationController` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll be using View Controller Containment (see WWDC 2011 Session 102 ADC video). So your root controller would most likely be a a subclass of UIViewController, btw  UINavigationController is not intended to be subclassed (according to Apple docs).